# How do I address all sub-elements in a list-of-lists?

Tags: r

This seems like a simple question, but I'm stuck!

How can I address all elements in sub-list given I have a list of identical lists?

```
 a <- list(a = "ayy", b = "bee", c = "cee") 
 b <- list(a = "1", b = "2", c = "3")       
 l1 <- list(a,b)
```

I'd like to be able to return `l1$b`, or `l1[TRUE]$b`, but this syntax doesn't appear to work.

I am expecting to get back something like this:

```
[[1]]         
[1] "bee"     

[[2]]         
[1] "2"
```

It seems easy enough to do in a for loop, but that doesn't feel R-y enough.

Comment: `lapply(l1, '[[', 2)`

Comment: or `lapply(l1, \`[[\`, "b")`

Comment: `list.map(l1, b)` using `rlist` package

Comment: These should be answers, as I have questions that won't work well in a comment format.

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(1:length(l1),function(x)l1[[x]]$b)
[[1]]
[1] "bee"

[[2]]
[1] "2"
```